# Simplify $8i^6+6i^5-5i^3-3i^2-7i-9$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

> Simplify $8i^6+6i^5-5i^3-3i^2-7i-9$.
>
> Answer choices:
>
> 1. $-14 +4i$
> 2. $-4+4i$
> 3. $-10i$
> 4. $-14-18i$

When I solved this, none of the choices matched. First, I assumed if $i$ had an even exponent generally the answer is $-1$ and simplified my equation into the following steps.

1. $-8+6i^5-5i^3+3-7i-9$
2. $-14+6i^5-5i^3-7i$

I do not know if there is another to further simplify or if these are the correct first steps. How would you answer this problem?

Comment: It does not fall under algebraic topology.

Comment: $i^3=-i{{{}}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $i^6= -1,i^5=i,i^4 =1,i^3 = -i,i^2= -1.$  So the answer to your question is $-14 + 4i.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$i^{4k+n}=i^n$$

$$i^1=i,\ i^2=-1,\ i^3=-i,\ i^4=1$$